# Horizontal list element evenly spaced and responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am creating an unordered list that contains images and text, and would like each item to be 1/3rd the width with a margin, evenly spaced. I can't figure out how to ensure, in a responsive website, the items are always exactly 1/3rd the width, including margins. Percentages seem to not remain consistent across browsers.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><img>Text</li>
    <li><img>Text</li>
    <li><img>Text</li>
    <li><img>Text</li>
    <li><img>Text</li>
    <li><img>Text</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {list-style:none; text-align:center; margin:0;}
ul li {display:inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; vertical-align:top; width:32%; margin:10px 1%;}
```

If I want two rows of three columns here, it will sometimes look fine and other times push the third item down to the next row--almost as if some browsers are adding a pixel or two somewhere. Is there CSS that I can use to just space it evenly across the entire width of the parent element?

Note that the site is responsive so calculating exact pixels isn't going to work. I'd also rather avoid writing separate CSS for different browsers, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to tackle this, but the easiest CSS solution is to use inline-blocks for the `li` elements. Now the issue with inline-block is, they will take whitespace into account, breaking your layout, but there are two easy solutions for this in the markup:

1. HTML comments between the `li` elements;
2. Compressed HTML code.

Example with HTML comments:

```
<ul>
    <li><img>Text</li><!--
 --><li><img>Text</li><!--
 --><li><img>Text</li><!--
 --><li><img>Text</li><!--
 --><li><img>Text</li><!--
 --><li><img>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Example with compressed HTML:

```
<ul><li><img>Text</li><li><img>Text</li><li><img>Text</li><li><img>Text</li><li><img>Text</li><li><img>Text</li></ul>
```

For the CSS, this should do the trick (you can modify the width of the 'columns' in media queries).

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
  }

@media screen and (min-width: 20em) {

  li {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

}
```

Another thing to note is that you can't use margins on the left and right of these items, as they will not be part of the original width, but you can use padding on the inside to "space" elements apart. This is also how some of the repsonsive grid systems are built (a little more advanced, but same principle).

Here's the live code: http://codepen.io/TheDutchCoder/pen/zxxwom

Comment: Reinier, thank you. This is an interesting solution. First, are there any cross-browser exceptions I need to think about? Second, I'm playing around now and using margins on the <li> elements as a percentage, subtracting that from the width of the <li>. Do you see an issue in modifying in that way?

Comment: Check my solution below for a fully supported cross-browser solution. I've seen problems with this inline-block hack (adding comments to remove space). If you define your box-sizing to border-box then you can use padding instead of margin to space your li elements. The interesting element in the above answer is the use of the @media query, you will need it to define breakpoints in your responsive layout. Good luck!

Comment: First off: this is not a hack, it's a prefectly fine solution, but some poepl don't realize that whitespace plays a part in this situation.

Floating elements is fine, but it takes the elements out of the current document flow, which is not always a good idea.

Inline-block is really powerful for layouts, until we get a better solution that is supported by most browsers. Flexbox is a good example too.

Comment: @NathanS Not many concerns, it's suppored by IE8+ and works with IE7 with some small additions. All other browsers work fine with it. Using percentages for margins is fine as long as the percentages add up of course, it's a fine way of spacing elements, but it depends on the container's width of course.

Comment: @ReinierKaper I'm not saying it is not a good solution, I'm just saying that I have seen people having issues with this technique. Floating vs inline-block for layouts has always been a useless debate: both techniques were not made for layout purposes. Two modules has been researched to build flexible layouts: The CSS Template Layout Module (which is just a draft) and the Flexible Box Layout Module which is a working solution if you don't need to target browsers below IE10 and Opera Mini. For learning purposes: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Pipo yes of course, they're both not made for what they're used for, but in general inline-blocks behave a little more "predictable" if you will, because they stay in the document's flow, as opposed to floats that you have to clear.

It doesn't matter much and I hope a better solution will see the light very, very soon with good support ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cross-browser solution. I have added an html5 structure if you need to include images in your list.

```css
/* the two following properties modify the box-model so that padding is removed from the width instead of being added */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul:after { /* to clearfix your ul list */
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
ul li {
  display: block; /* inline-block have an extra 4px margin wich makes it harder to use in this situation */
  width: 33.3333333%; /* You get it (100/3) but use exact number */
  padding: 10px 5px;
  float: left; /* if you use block elements you have to float them */
  text-align: center;
}
figure {
  margin: 0; /* to normalize figure element */
}
figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
      <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
      <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
      <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
      <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
      <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
      <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
 
</ul>
```

Comment: Great Work Pipo, can i have the list similar to this with counter too
[Click Here for Sample](http://www.magazinehive.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Breadcrumbs-Navigation-PSD-File.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/j13889cx/

I've added a `div` element wrapping everything inside each `li` element called `.ul-wrap`.

This allows you to add any margin/padding you'd like because `.ul-wrap` is a block element.

Try changing `.ul-wrap`'s margin or padding.