# CSS / JS - horizontal alignment of wrapping elements

Tags: javascript, css, html, flexbox

I have a problem creating a responsive layout of a set of inputs with labels.
I want them to stay in one line when there is enough horizontal space, otherwise wrap but stay horizontally aligned.

Lets show it on pictures.

This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I got so far:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnbevbvb/)

The blue element is always the same width so is not a problem.
The orange elements have different widths and I want them to align horizontally.
I cannot set them to the same width, because then they will waste space when in single line.

What I tried so far:

1. `display: table-cell`

   The problem is it can't wrap.
2. Container: `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` Children aligned to the right.

   The problem was the container doesn't shrink to the children width
   when they wrap, so whole group moved to the right side which is not
   what I want.
3. *Using JS to set equal widths of orange elements.*

   The problem is they should have equal widths only when the line is
   wrapped, and I don't see a reliable way to detect whether it is
   wrapped or not.

**Any** solutions welcome. I don't mind if it is not pure-CSS solution, I lost hope such one exists.

Edit: The difference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023641/horizontal-list-element-evenly-spaced-and-responsive) is that elements have varying widths, both between rows and within one row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal list element evenly spaced and responsive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023641/horizontal-list-element-evenly-spaced-and-responsive)

Comment: The difference here is that elements have varying widths, both between rows and within one row.

Comment: [Flexbox Justification](https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/) ?

Comment: I don't see a way to apply Flexbox Justification to get the effect I want.

Comment: At least, reply to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for this particular case:

```
.A {
  margin-left: 53px;
}

.C1 {
  margin-left: -53px;
}

.C2 {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50vjj3sk/1/)

The values of the margin would have to be recalculated in JS when labels change, which can happen in my case.

This is partial solution, because unfortunately it wouldn't work if first label is the shorter one, which also can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
label{display:inline-block;width:130px;text-align:right;}
div.inner{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="inner">

<label>Please Enter Name:</label><input type="text"> 

</div> 

<div class="inner"> 

<label> Address:</label><input type="text"> 

</div>
```

**Results:**

**Case 1: When Full width available**

[image]

**Case 2: When width is shrinked**

[image]

Comment: This is equal to #3 thing from the list of things I tried, except with hardcoded width.

The problem is the label wastes horizontal space when line is not wrapped.
And hardcoding the width gives more potential problems.

Comment: Use `display:flex-box;` for container of both inner divs. Then `flex-grow:1;` for .inner

Comment: Still the same problem I mentioned above.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wLqLg0w/)

[Image](http://prntscr.com/di3cmn)